# Unable to get keys on redis cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redis-cli

I have created a cache key on redis cluster with cacheKey as "citylist_[object Object]"

When i am trying to get the keys on cluster mode with pattern  `keys citylist*` on redis. It is returning me `(empty array)`

but when i am trying to get the value directly using `get "citylist_[object Object]"` , it returns me the value.

how to search the keys using the pattern for above mentioned cache key.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple test on my local Redis (v6.2.4):

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set "citylist_[object Object]" test_value
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> keys citylist*
1) "citylist_[object Object]"
```

Comment: This works correctly on single instance redis, but doesnt seem to work over redis-cluster (managed by AWS)